# What types of numbers may MX records use for weight?

Tags: email, dns, smtp, numbers, mx-record

For example, could one use a real number as an MX weight? Is there a limit to how many decimal places an MX weight may have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MX weight/preference/distance is transmitted as 16 bit **integer** (from 0 to 65535=0xFFFF).

I do not remember seeing use of MX preferences above 1_000.

[RFC-1035 : 3.3.9. MX RDATA format](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt)